# How to set a scroll view inside a Linear Layout in Android xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this xml code,I want to set a scroll view for these buttons.Can anybody help me? It is showing error when i set a scroll view inside the layout.The xml contain some buttons and textviews .Textviews and buttons are aligned horizontally inside a Linear Layout with vertical orientation.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.cozyne.toglebtn.MainActivity" >


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" > 



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTopBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#00ff00"
    android:dividerPadding="22dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:00 AM" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:text="ON" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#00ff00"
    android:dividerPadding="22dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:00 AM" 
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:text="ON" />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `ScrollView` must have only `single Child Layout`.

Comment: Set the ScrollView as the **root element** (swap the LinearLayoiut and the ScrollView). Also remind to **close** the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollView can have only one direct child

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context="com.cozyne.toglebtn.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTopBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#00ff00"
        android:dividerPadding="22dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12:00 AM" />
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:text="ON" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#00ff00"
        android:dividerPadding="22dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12:00 AM" />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:text="ON" />
     </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that You have not ended up with the xml. You have to put the

```
</LinearLayout>
```

Tag at the end. You started with a LinearLayout as the parent container and put inside the scrollView. Then You put again a LinearLayout inside etc... . But at the end of Your xml, You don´t close the parent LinearLayout....

The second issue is, that You have more than one view inside the ScrollView. You have two LinearLayouts inside, just make one view inside a scrollView. It´s not allowed to put more than one inside scrollView...

### EDIT

and finally, like **Rubén Jiménez** said, You missed the tag at the end of Your textView. That edit is just for the sake of completeness...

Answer (score 1):

You also missed the "/>" at the final of the textView.

Change it for:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:00 AM" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplest soultion:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">
              <!-- Add up your Content -->
        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```